# How to validate the user JWT pass over Token is correct

Tags: validation, jwt, token

My mean is not validate a correct format Token.

According to [jwt/README.md at 3.2 · lcobucci/jwt](https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/blob/3.2/README.md#validating)
This validate is validating a correct format Token, but when I set a value like `http://example.org/token/123.123.123`，this library will throw an exception, like this:

[image]

How to validate the user JWT pass over Token is correct with 2 dots?

Comment: I think you have fundamentally misunderstood what JWT is. "123.123.123" is *not* a valid token. A token isn't just random numbers, it has a specific structure and meaning.

Comment: Thank you reply me, I think you misunderstood what I mean. Right, 123.123.123 is not a valid token, but I need to verify this value because I can't confirm if the user will pass in a valid value. @IMSoP

Comment: In that case, maybe it's the way exceptions work that you didn't understand? See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to pre-validate anything, because the library is giving you an exception; the purpose of exceptions is that they can be caught in order to handle the situation. So all you need is this:

```
try {
    $token_info = (new Parser())->parse((string) $token_string);
    // successful
} catch(RuntimeException $e) {
    // unsuccessful
}
```

Comment: ，boom shit, I completely forgot about the exception...Thank you very much! I was very sorry for wasting so much time.

Answer (score 0):

I already have a solution, share to all:

```
// $token from a HTTP request.
// Must have 2 dots.
if (substr_count($token, '.') === 2) {
    $preValidToken = base64_decode($token);
    // Get decoded token's last '}' position.
    $lastPos = strrpos($preValidToken, '}');
    if ($lastPos) {
        // Assemble Json string.
        $preValidToken = '[' . substr($preValidToken, 0, $lastPos + 1) . ']';
        $preValidToken = str_replace('}{', '},{', $preValidToken);
        // Convert to associative array.
        $preValidToken = json_decode($preValidToken, true);
        if ($preValidToken && is_array($preValidToken)) {
            var_dump($preValidToken);
            die;
            $token = (new Parser())->parse((string) $token);
            // Parses from a string
            // Do something here...
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode([
    'code' => 205,
    'msg' => 'Token not valid '
]);
exit();
```

If valided, `$preValidToken` will be a `array`, content like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'typ' => string 'JWT' (length=3)
      'alg' => string 'HS256' (length=5)
      'jti' => string '123123123' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      'iss' => string 'http://example.org' (length=13)
      'jti' => string '123123123' (length=9)
      'iat' => int 1524314239
      'nbf' => int 1524314299
      'exp' => int 1524317839
      'uid' => int 1
```

And then, we can verify that the token is valid through verifying this array, if no problem, we can execute next code line `$token = (new Parser())->parse((string) $token);` without error.

**I do not know if there is a better way?**

Comment: All you're doing here is the same thing the library is already doing for you: decoding the JSON, and detecting if there was an error while doing so. Leave that to the library, and handle the error it indicates to you.

Comment: Thank you, thank you...I feel very sorry for my stupidity. @IMSoP